# Running a .NET Core Console Application

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a console app from a project template, but I am running into multiple bugs.

Can someone please create a console app and explain what information I need to change in order for it to run? It should be very simple.

Link: https://medium.com/@utterbbq/c-serializing-list-of-objects-to-csv-9dce02519f6b

Summary:

I am unsure if I am supposed to insert values into these property types or to leave blank. I believe this half is similar to filling out a model form?

```
 void Main()
        {
            var rentInvoiceType = typeof(ClientClass);
            var properties = typeof(ClientClass).GetProperties()
             .Where(n =>
             n.PropertyType == typeof(string)
             || n.PropertyType == typeof(bool)
             || n.PropertyType == typeof(char)
             || n.PropertyType == typeof(byte)
             || n.PropertyType == typeof(decimal)
             || n.PropertyType == typeof(int)
             || n.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)
             || n.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?));
```

For the last half, I am receiving errors under the 'var output' value, 'var delimiter' value, the instance if the 'items' in item, 'null' , the value of 'n', and '.Aggregate'.

```
            var output = “”;
            var delimiter = ‘;’;
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var header = properties
                .Select(n => n.Name)
                .Aggregate((a, b) => a + delimiter + b);

                sw.WriteLine(header);

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    var row = properties
                    .Select(n => n.GetValue(item, null))
                    .Select(n => n == null ? “null” : n.ToString())
                .Aggregate((a, b) => a + delimiter + b);

                    sw.WriteLine(row);
                }

                output = sw.ToString();
            }
            return output;
```

Comment: if you are getting any error, then please post it here

Answer (score 0):

> I am receiving errors under the 'var output' value,

From the example, you need to replace single ( ‘ ’ ) and double ( “ ” ) quotes with ( ' ' ) and ( " " ).

> and '.Aggregate'

Add:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq; // <=
```

> I am unsure if I am supposed to insert values into these property type

Put your values in the class you have defined (not in the 'PropertyType'):

```
var rentInvoice = new RentInvoice()
{
    Car = "Lotus",
    Price = 1234,
    ...
};
```

> the instance if the 'items' in item,

And add the class to 'items':

```
var items = new List<RentInvoice>();
items.Add(rentInvoice);
```